# Merge all *csv and remove duplicate headers using command prompt except top row

Tags: cmd

copy *.csv merge.csv is working to merge but not able to remove headers from it so I need to remove all headers except top one

Comment: There is a search facility at the top of the page; please use it. Your exact problem has been handled on multiple occasions before. _As a result of your lack of shown effort, I have downvoted your question_.